# Grails springSecurityService in resources.groovy gives null current user

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-bean

I'm using Grails 2.4.3 and in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy,

```
beans = {
    someBean(com.domain.SomeBeanImpl) {
        springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
    }
}
```

But inside `SomeBeanImpl` class,

```
class SomeBeanImpl {
    def springSecurityService

    def method() {
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser  //null, even after successful log-in
    }
}
```

In my controllers and services, I can normally retrieve `springSecurityService.currentUser`.

Why is it **null** on the custom bean? How to properly retrieve it?

**EDITED:**

I used `grails mt-spring-security` from http://multi-tenant.github.io/grails-multi-tenant-single-db/docs/v0.8.3/guide/4.%20Scripts.html#4.2.%20mt-spring-security,

and using springSecurityService bean in this class,

```
/**
 * Spring Security Tenant Resolver
 * Extracts the tenantId
 * @see http://multi-tenant.github.com/grails-multi-tenant-single-db/
 */
@Log4j
class SpringSecurityTenantResolver implements TenantResolver {
    def springSecurityService

    Integer resolve(HttpServletRequest request) throws TenantResolveException {
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
/*

        if (!user) {
            throw new TenantResolveException('Tenant could not be resolved using SpringSecurity')
        }
*/

        log.debug "${request.requestURL} : ${user?.username} : ${user?.tenantId}"
        return user?.tenantId
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this bean used? Is it called during a web request? If not, there's not going to be an authenticated user.

Answer (score -1):

try adding `bean.autowire = 'byName'` into the bean definition

Comment: The bean is injected correctly, but it's returning null from the method call. autowire isn't relevant.